Record unique values from a Google Sheets column (even if data changes) and copy that data to another sheet
Sorry I am new to scripting. I am trying to record the values from a column in a Google Sheet. This data is dynamic and changes every month via an importrange.
I would like to record the all-time list of the values in this column and not just the current(live) values.
So basically when the data changes once a month I would like a column in another sheet to be populated with any new and unique values in the new data while retaining the unique values from the previous months.
I have tried this script but it only updates based on the live data. I need it to copy the unique data instead and retain it.
Lets say that the data for January data looks something like this in column A. I need just the uniques values with duplicates removed as displayed in column B. My current script achieves this.



Column A
Column B




apples
apples


bannanas
bannanas


apples



bannanas




In february the data imported into column A may contain completely new unique values but I would like column B to show the unique values for January and Feburary.



Column A
Column B




Pears
apples


Peaches
bannanas


Pears
Pears


Oranges
Oranges


Oranges
Peaches



    const getUnique_ = array2d => [...new Set(array2d.flat())];
    const uniquifyAColumn = (sheetName = 'Sheet1', column = 1, headers = 1) => {
      const sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName),
      rg = sh.getRange(1 + headers, column, sh.getLastRow() - headers, 1),
      values = rg.getValues(),
      uniqueValues = getUnique_(values).map(e => [e]);
    rg.offset(0, 1, uniqueValues.length).setValues(uniqueValues);
    };


Would you please explain the significance of the "current data". Would you please edit the question to include an example of the "existing all-time list" , and the expected outcome of the all-time list based on the "current data".

Thanks @Tedinoz, I have made edits. Hopefully this makes sense.

You want to build a list of Unique codes based on accumulating monthly data.
The question includes a snippet of code; the problem is that this script replaces the existing codes with the new codes rather than appending the codes. However there is not enough code to create a complete script.
So, consider this answer.
Compared to the snippet, the key is to combine the existing codes with the new codes, and update the sheet with the combined codes.

function getUniqueCodes(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var activeName = "February"
  var targetName = "Unique Codes"
  var thisMonth = ss.getSheetByName(activeName)
  var uniqueSheet = ss.getSheetByName(targetName)

  // get this months data 
  var aVals = thisMonth.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var aLast = aVals.filter(String).length;
  var thisMonthRange = thisMonth.getRange(1,1,aLast)
  var thisMonthData = thisMonthRange.getValues()
  Logger.log("DEBUG: this month range "+thisMonthRange.getA1Notation())
  Logger.log(thisMonthData) // DEBUG
  var unique = thisMonthData.flat().filter(onlyUnique)
  Logger.log(unique) // DEBUG
  Logger.log("DEBUG: number of unique codes = "+unique.length)

  // get the existing unique codes
  var lr = uniqueSheet.getLastRow()
  var existingUniqueRange = uniqueSheet.getRange(1,1,lr)
  var existingUniqueData = existingUniqueRange.getValues()
  Logger.log(existingUniqueData) // DEBUG
  var updatedUniqueData = existingUniqueData
  // add the new unique codes to thr existing codes
  for (let i=0; i < unique.length; i++) {
    updatedUniqueData.push([unique[i]]);
  }
  Logger.log(updatedUniqueData) // DEBUG

  // paste the updated unque codes to the sheet
  uniqueSheet.getRange(1,1,updatedUniqueData.length).setValues(updatedUniqueData)

}
function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
  Logger.log("value ="+value+", index = "+index+", self = "+self)
  return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}


h/t @MikeSteelson How to get the unique items out of a list in Google Apps Script?

SAMPLE - Before

SAMPLE - After


